# Does the number of particles per energy level increase or decrease with rising temperature?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

From a previous question, I understood that at very high temperature $T$, thus a very high total energy $U$, the number of particles at each energy level $n_j$ would be very low, e.g. the particles are spread over more energy levels.

This is also supported by the fact that the number of microstates $\Omega$ increases with increasing total energy $U$ shown by:
$$\frac{d \ln(\Omega)}{dU}= \frac{1}{k_B\cdot T}$$
That's because an increase in number of possible microstates $\Omega$ means there are more ways to order particles which can only be achieved if they are spread over more energy levels, thus the number of particles per energy level decreases.

However, looking at the concluded Boltzmann formula for the number of particles at an energy level $n_j$:
$$n_j = e^{-\frac{E_j}{k_BT}}\cdot \frac{N}{\sum_{j=1}^n e^{-\frac{E_j}{k_BT}}}$$
...shows that as temperature $T$ increases, the number of particles at each energy level $n_j$ **increases** instead of decreases.

Why do they contradict each other or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: can you give the link to the previous question and also where the definition of energy levels  is give? Energy levels are quantum mechanical, states  the Bottzman formula  is for classical particles afaik

Comment: @annav My previous question was about having only 1 particle per energy level that I emailed to a physics professor. His answer: *Since there is a very large number of particles, if we put only one particle per energy level and keep going to higher energy levels, the sum of the energies will make U a very large number, and so this is a possibility only if a very large U is associated with the system. Therefore as you get to higher and higher temperatures it approaches the limit you are suggesting.*

Definition energy states: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics

Comment: @annav Also, if you plot the MB Distribution in terms of energy level $E$ and increase the temperature in the formula, you can see that the curve flattens out more and more over all energy states, meaning that each energy state is getting equally probable e.g. the total number of particles is getting spread more and more equally over each energy state.

This all is clashing with the formula for $n_j$ in my OP saying that the number of particles in an energy state increases with temperature. If you plot $n_j$ you'd see that it increases with increasing temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, but I am not able to use the concept of quantum mechanical "energy level" with this classical treatment. It reminds me of the conflict between data and classical black body theory, where the quantum had to be invented . There also with increasing temperature you get classically an increase in frequencies.   http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html Sorry not to be able to help

Comment: @JohnnyGui, "...shows that as temperature $T$ increases, the number of particles at each energy level $n_j$ increases instead of decreases" - cannot understand this, it shows that at higher energy levels increases, at lower  energy levels decreases, why at each ?

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist I solved my problem, I didn't write the partition function for the formula of $n_j$ correctly when I tried to plot this. When increasing temperature, you can now see $n_j$ decreases at low energy levels and increases at higher energy levels, just like how the probability changes in the MB Distribution when increasing the tempreature. So both formulas agree that the total number of particles gets spread out evenly over more energy levels as temperature increases.